# Inconsistent units?

Tags: units

I have reviewed this statement until my eyes hurt; can someone tell me why the units output aren't lb/ft^2?

```
VelocityPressureConstant = (1/
     2)[(0.0765 lb/ft^3)/(32.2 ft/s^2)][(mile/
     hour) (5280 ft/mile) (hour/3600 s)]^2
```

Comment: Perhaps this question is better for Physics.SE or Math.SE or Engineering.SE or DimensionalAnalysis.SE? Also: put parentheses around `3600 s`.

Comment: Also, square brackets have definite meaning in Mathematica, you cannot use them like parentheses for grouping terms.

Comment: hour = 3600 s;mile = 5280 ft; VelocityPressureConstant = 1/2(0.0765 lb/ft^3)/(32.2 ft/s^2) (mile/hour)^2 results in 0.00255528 lb/ft^2

Comment: Use Basic Math Input palette to enter your expression in Mathematica

Answer (score 3):

Your expression rewritten to remove grouping errors:

```
VelocityPressureConstant = 
  (1/2) ((0.0765 lb/ft^3)/(32.2 ft/s^2)) ((mile/hour) (5280 ft/mile) (hour/(3600 s)))^2
```

> ```
> (0.00255528*lb)/ft^2
> ```

Don't use square brackets as second level parentheses in *Mathematica*.

Comment: I now understand the problem.  Thanks very much to everyone who took the time to review my question, and especially to those who took the time to post comments.

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth one can use the Unit system in Mathematica. Frankly I find it difficult and verbose to use but with practice one can master it.

In the expression below the UnitConvert was used with a Quantity as an input and also a Quantity as the target unit (there are other approaches).

It looks strange to have a numerical value for the second Quantity that doesn't match however the documentation indicates that when one uses a Quantity as a target unit, the magnitude is ignored.

```
1/2*Quantity[0.0765, "Pounds"/("Feet")^3]/ Quantity[32.2,"Feet"/("Seconds")^2]*
(UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Miles"/"Hours"], Quantity[1, "Feet"/"Seconds"]])^2
```

the answer is

```
Quantity[0.00255528, ("Pounds")/("Feet")^2]
```

In the notebook the answer will print as:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Units]

```
VelocityPressureConstant =
 1/2*(0.0765 lb)/ft^3*s^2/(32.2* ft)*(mile/hour*(5280 ft)/mile*hour/(3600 s))^2
(* (0.00255528 lb)/ft^2)* )
```

It is nice to use Basic Math Palette to input data and also not to make mistakes.